# JFace Tableviewer empty - display string

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, tableviewer

I'm developing an eclipse RCP/RAP application. I have several GUI-classes that use the *JFace TableViewer* (internal *org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table*). 
Some of my clients mentioned that it is a little confusing wether the "database-select failed" or there are just no elements.

So here's my question. Is there any way to display a "greyed out" text saying "No elements". There is something similar for the *org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text*:

```
edtTest.setMessage("Please enter something");
```

Couldn't find anything like that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any simple support for this.

You could simulate this by adding a dummy row to the table and making your label provider implement `IColorProvider` so you can set the color of the row (or use one of the label providers based on `StyledCellLabelProvider`.

Alternatively use a separate label  control and use `StackLayout` to make either the table of the label the visible control.